# Does Server Ram work on a normal computer?

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard

I need some help on choosing RAM for my computer. I have 2GB on my PC, and I am on a 32bit machine so I can only get up to 4GB of RAM. I am trying to find a x2 DDR2 PC2-5300 2GB for my computer, and the question is, does Workstation (Server) RAM work on a normal computer?

```
Kingston Technology
4GB Low Power Single-Rank Kit
Manufacturer Part# KTH-XW9400LPK2/4G
Memory, Technology: DDR2 SDRAM
Memory Size: 4 GB
Memory Speed: 667 MHz
Memory Standard: DDR2-667/PC2-5300,
ECC Memory needs MB Compatibility
```

Can I buy this server RAM, and will it work on my PC?

And I have 2 stocks, 1GB on the first and 1BG on the other. The first ram has 266MHz and the second ram has 333Mhz. If I buy for example, 2 2GB ram with 800MHz, will it work correctly? Or do I have to buy 2 rams with 266Mhz or 333Mhz?

```
My MotherBoard:
Model: ConRoe1333-D667
Chipset: Intel i945G Rev. A2
Southbridge: Intel 82801GB (ICH7/R) Rev.A1
LPCIO: WinBond W83627EHF

Bios: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: P1.80
Date: 12/10/2007
```

Comment: You won't find DDR2 RAM running at 1600MHz, you must have been looking at DDR3

Comment: @Psycogeek , i added my motherboard info now.

Comment: @misha256 how about 800Mhz? Will the 2 2gb rams work with 800Mhz?

Comment: @OWSAP Yes DDR2 800MHz sticks will work just fine. Your motherboard will clock them to what it's capable of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow I didn't expect there to be such a lack of clarity in the various answers and comments. Here's a definitive answer:

- ConRoe1333-D667 *does not support ECC RAM*. It *will not boot* if you install ECC RAM.
- All revisions of ConRoe1333-D667, whether 1.x or 2.x, are limited to a maximum RAM speed of 667MHz. If you install 800Mhz RAM, it will run at 667Mhz.

So to be clear, the very best you can do for your PC is **two sticks of 2GB DDR2 Non-ECC RAM**. Because you were looking at Kingston yourself, I'm happy to point you here:

http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/?partid=kvr800d2n6/2g

If you still feel like buying Server RAM go nuts, but it won't work ;-)

Comment: Which is the reason I voted those unclear answers as being unhelpful.  This is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that even if the Server RAM does fit, boot, and runs your desktop you might not be getting what you bargained for.

I don't know if the RAM will work on your Desktop (nor do I care to find out) I do know that it wouldn't be what you expected.

I will give you a link to a YouTube video that answers your question (with ram, cpus, hard drives, etc);

[Servers vs Desktop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByI1PHMcPJQ)

Granted this guy really simplifies it but it drives the point home.

Server RAM is designed to last longer, have fewer RAM errors, and have greater capacity.

At a **greater** cost than desktop RAM!

With seeing how old your MOBO is, you would be better off (a lot better off) just getting the desktop ram (you would save a bit of money too).

[DDR2 ram on newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007611%20600528632&IsNodeId=1&name=DDR2)

[Your MOBO specs](http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/conroe1333-d667%20r1.0/) - Please check this page! It has the specifics on what type of ram you should get

Comment: It says that my board supports DDR2 667/533 but can't it support 800Mhz? /Thanks for the reply

Comment: Quick question I looked on google for those specs with specifically what you gave me but as you can tell the title of the specs page has the same name but ends with R1.0. I do not know if there is a different version of this motherboard under the same name (Maybe a r2.0). However just to be sure can you download and run CPU-z and go to the motherboard tab and see for sure what your MOBO is. Your MOBO might have been able to support 800MHz because it might be a revised MOBO version

Comment: Why post "I don't know the answer to the question"?

Answer (score 1):

We need to know your motherboard make and model to be sure.

I've seen mixed results in my time. Some non-ECC capable motherboards will handle ECC RAM fine and others not.

If you're buying new RAM, get non-ECC RAM:

KVR800D2N6/2G

You'll still find them. They're rated max 800MHz, but your PC will run them at 400/533/667 depending on what it's capable of.

**EDIT:** Based on your motherboard details, you must purchase standard *non-ECC* RAM.

Comment: Why have two answers on the same question?